# git cloning gnome core suite

Tags: git, clone, gnome

I am trying to download the `gnome` core suite from `git` repository, but I need help because I do not understand how `git` works. In https://git.gnome.org/browse/ there is the list of all the `gnome` projects. I can download a single individual project, like for example `clutter`.

How do I download all the projects that are in the core suite?
I mean that I need to download the minimal source code for compiling `gnome`.

Instructions for downloading anonymously `gnome` with `git` are here https://wiki.gnome.org/Git/Developers

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to clone them one by one, following the [Getting the code section](https://wiki.gnome.org/Git/Developers#Getting_Code):

```
git clone git://git.gnome.org/adwaita-icon-theme
git clone git://git.gnome.org/at-spi2-atk
git clone git://git.gnome.org/at-spi2-core
...
```

The idea is that you rarely need *all* of them and should be able to pick and chose the ones you actually need to clone locally.

If the git protocol is blocked (port 9418), you could try the http one:

> With Git 1.6.6 and newer, http is possible too (please use the git protocol though!):

```
 git clone http://git.gnome.org/browse/[project]
```

Comment: I want to install `gnome` on my academic cluster and I only need the minimal version (because otherwise I am stuck with `twm`). Which projects do I need to download?

Comment: @simona why download source projects to install gnome? Why not an `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` (or another distribution if this is not Ubuntu), as in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/Installation?

Comment: @simona then you need to go to an admin: using the sources would mean recompiling *and* installing: the install step would *also* require root privilege anyway.

Comment: @simona yes, but installing gnome will involve /usr/local/(bin | lib) for it to work properly, no?, and that will involve admin.

Comment: if I can install an application in a local folder, for example emacs, why is gnome different?

Comment: @simona because it is much more complex than *one* application (like Emacs): see https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeLove/BuildGnome

Comment: is there a desktop environment that you raccommand, that I can easily install by myself?

Comment: @simona to my knowledge, any Linux desktop (http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/best-alternative-linux-desktops-5-reviewed-and-rated-1126947) isn't easy to just compile and install locally.

Answer (score 1):

[JHBuild](https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/) is the recommended way to build and run GNOME development code.

You will need the development libraries of the dependencies. Some of them are taken for granted, some others will be downloaded and built on demand. All in all, `JHBuild` takes the information from the module sets to know what are the dependencies, where to grab them and finally build them.

There are several guides to use JHBuild to build GNOME, I prefer the [How Do I](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Jhbuild) version, though your mileage might vary.